# Compare dates from a string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
$Deldate = "19-06-2018"
$Newdate = "04-06-2018"
```

I need to check which date is bigger.

```
if ($Deldate -ge $NewDate) {
    write-host "NewDate is bigger"
} 
else {
    write-host "Deldate is bigger"
}
```

This is not working for me, and it looks like the format is not "System.DateTime". I'm getting the date values are from an external CSV file. How do I find a solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to cast the strings that you have created to the "datetime" type like so:

```
$Deldate = "19-06-2018"
$Newdate = "04-06-2018"

$Deldate = [datetime]::ParseExact("$Deldate", 'dd-MM-yyyy', $null)
$Newdate = [datetime]::ParseExact("$Newdate", 'dd-MM-yyyy', $null)

if ($Deldate -ge $NewDate) {
    write-output "NewDate is bigger than or equal to"
}
else {
    write-output "Deldate is bigger"
}
```

This returns the correct result. You can't simply use the Get-Date cmdlet, since the `-Date` required parameter also requires that the parameter be of type "DateTime", so you first have to cast the strings to the DateTime type.

Comment: Maybe someday we'll start playing nice with other date formats.  For now, though, using the ParseExact method will *always* get the right answer no matter your locale.

Comment: I have to say I like this suggestion way-way more than what I'd proposed. It's not as "powershelly" as Get-Date, but it's a hell of a lot more reliable and its concise. You get my vote for answer.

Comment: Yeah - I agree with you @Adam it feels dirty calling this a "PowerShell" answer when it's really .NETty, but if it works we can only complain so much, haha

Comment: @BryceMcDonald: Indeed, it seems like calling the .NET framework directly is currently the only option - let's try to change that: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6995

Comment: Re "you first have to cast the strings to the DateTime type": Can I suggest you reword that part? PowerShell's parameter binding will _implicitly_ convert a `[string]` argument to `[datetime]` when passed to `-Date`, and in this particular instance it will actually respect the _current_ culture, unlike in the vast majority of cases in PowerShell, where the _invariant_ culture is by design applied; however, this should be considered a _bug_ - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6989. So, `Get-Date "19-06-2018"` actually works with e.g. culture `de-DE` in effect, but _shouldn't_.

Answer (score 2):

**Originally Proposed...**

I am going to change the format of your date just a hair from `DD-MM-YYYY` to `MM-DD-YYYY`:

```
$Deldate = Get-Date "06-19-2018"
$Newdate = Get-Date "06-04-2018"
if ($Deldate -gt $Newdate) { 
    'Deldate is larger'
} 
else {
    'Newdate is larger or equal'
}
```

I'm creating two date objects based on the respective dates you gave. I'm comparing the two objects; PowerShell knows how to do the date math.

It works fine for U.S. style dates.

**After much discussion...**

However, for non-US style dates, consider calling datetime's constructor:

```
$Deldate = New-object 'datetime' -ArgumentList 2018, 6, 19, $null, $null, $null
$Newdate = New-object 'datetime' -ArgumentList 2018, 6, 4, $null, $null, $null
if ($Deldate -gt $Newdate) { 'Deldate is larger' } else { 'Newdate is larger or equal' }
```

Or, as proposed the `[datetime]::ParseExact()` method; documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This won't work, you can't use a string for the `-Date` parameter (can verify this with `Get-Help Get-Date`)

Comment: Passing a string date does an implicit `datetime` cast. It'd be the same as `Get-Date $([datetime]'06-04-2018')`. Works fine.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh -- US PowerShell has an interesting relationship with EU style dates.  I imagine you're from across the pond?  Running your code I get `Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "19-06-2018" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid 
DateTime."`

Comment: @Adam: Note that the OP is _given_ the date strings in the specific format shown in the question (via a CSV file), and whether that format works with `Get-Date` depends on the current culture; with `en-US` (US English) in effect, it will _not_ work.
In short: This answer works only works if the input strings happen to be formatted according to the current culture's (`$PSCulture`) rules.

Comment: @_brycemcdonald If I remember right (and I'm getting old, memory wasn't what it was), that implicit cast to a `datetime` calls the class' underlying Parse() method, which supports a few date/time formats but as you noticed not dd-MM-yyyy. Microsoft recommends the ParseExact() method if the format isn't something Parse() knows. Lol! That's not confusing thought, right? :-)

Comment: Curiously, in this case an explicit cast - e.g., `[datetime] "19-06-2018"` - is _not_ equivalent to the implicit conversion that happens with `Get-Date "19-06-2018"`.
With explicit casts PowerShell _always_ uses the _invariant_ culture, so `[datetime] "19-06-2018"` _never_ works; this contrasts with `[datetime]::Parse("19-06-2018")` which _is_ culture-sensitive, like the `Get-Date` call. cc @BryceMcDonald

Comment: @mklement0 If you're right, I'd argue that is a bug. Microsoft states, "If the target type defines a Parse() method that takes that input, use that." [1] `datetime` has a Parse() method, which it should use. If `Parse()` is culture aware the implicit cast to `datetime` should pick that up.  --[1] https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2013/06/11/understanding-powershells-type-conversion-magic/

Comment: @Adam: The implicit conversion calls the _culture-sensitive_ `.Parse()` overload, whereas explicit casts in PowerShell expressly call the `.Parse()` overload that accepts a culture and - by design - passes the _invariant culture_, which, for the most part, is like `en-US`. PowerShell uses this technique consistently, so it applies to casting strings to numeric types as well.

Comment: @mklement0 Okay. I think I get what you're explaining, lemme restate to confirm. There are 3 versions of Parse() two of which take culture indicator (IFormatProvider). When Powershell does it's implicit conversion, it doesn't call either of those. It calls the one with no culture identifier, and in that case, that date format just bonks because it's not recognized.

Comment: @Adam: Yes; the single-argument `.Parse()` overload is effectively the same as passing `[cultureinfo]::currentculture` as the `IFormatProvider` argument. However, this implicit culture-sensitive conversion only happens for _compiled cmdlets_, not in _PowerShell code_; in the latter, implicit conversions too are culture-_invariant_, which is a surprising inconsistency - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6989

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is good with dates; it just has to know it's a date...

```
$Deldate = get-date "19-06-2018"
$Newdate = get-date "04-06-2018"

if ($Deldate -ge $NewDate) {
    write-host "NewDate is bigger"
}
else {
    write-host "Deldate is bigger"
}
```

Note: You could cast `[datetime]$Deldate ="19-06-2018"`, but as explained in comments to *[PowerTip: Convert String into DateTime Object](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/12/19/powertip-convert-string-into-datetime-object/)*, it's valid only for US date format.

Comment: But "19-06-2018" is not a valid US date (where the month comes first). Aren't you assuming particular versions of Windows for this code (presuming they use their corresponding default date format)?